# Mockito test - inject to autowired service

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to unit test Sprint Boot service (service A) which has autowired another service (service B) as

```
@Autowired
ServiceB serviceB;
```

Declaration for unit test looks like:

```
@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Mock
private ServiceA serviceA;

@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private ServiceB serviceB;

private User user;
```

and that will fail on

```
Mockito.when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);
User result = serviceA.upsertUser(user);
```

where serviceA `upsertUser()` method looks like

```
user = serviceB.doUpsertUser(user);
```

Test was working fine before I have switched in ServiceA `new` declaration of an user from

```
user = new ServiceB(userRepository).doUpsertUser(user);
```

to `@Autowired`

```
user = SeviceB.doUpsertUser(user);
```

I'm not sure if I have messed up with creating mocks and injecting mocks in a proper way as it comes when I stepped in ServiceA that ServiceB was not declared.

Comment: Are you using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class` in your test class? It's necessary to make autowiring works?

Comment: @KamilW Only `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` I will check with your suggestion

Comment: Change it to `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and let me know if it works.

Comment: @KamilW after switching to that all other Mockito tests stopped to work.

Comment: Now let's try remove `@Autowired` annotation and init mock by calling this method `@Before public void setUp() throws Exception {        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);}`

Comment: @KamilW Now it fails on all Mockito tests during the start on `MockitoJUnitRunner`

Comment: Try to do it with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and with changes from my previous comment.

Comment: With that it doesn't recognize to do with Mockito parts - failing with `RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate`

Comment: @KamilW My issue is almost the same like here https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/ and I have tried fix #2 w/o any luck

Comment: @KamilW I think that issues is in ServiceB as there is `@Autowire UserRepository userRepository` and test do not inject a mock of that userRespistory that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue following steps from https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/ for changes to `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` but there is no way to go away without `@InjectMocks`

My adjusted Mockito test looks like:

```
@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

@InjectMocks
private ServiceB serviceB;

private User user;
private ServiceA serviceA;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.serviceA = new ServiceA(userRepository, serviceB);
}

@Test
....
```